# Why does Firefox have an empty heap on Linux? Where does malloc go in memory?

Tags: linux, firefox, heap-memory

The start_brk and brk feild of mm_struct have same value for Firefox, which means the heap is empty in Firefox. Does anyone know: Why does Firefox have an empty heap on Linux? Where does malloc go in memory?

Comment: How are you determining that?

Comment: (Probably using custom allocators all round, mmap based.)

Comment: I print the mm_struct info in a kernel module for each process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox uses a custom memory allocator, [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/). Unless the `--enable-dss` option is specified during configuration, this allocator uses only `mmap()`, otherwise it uses both `sbrk()` and `mmap()`. Needless to say, only the `brk()` system call will modify the `start_brk` and `brk` fields of the struct in question.

Comment: I compiled a Firefox with --enable-dss, but the start_brk and brk still have same value. Do you know how to enable the brk heap allocation? What I want is jemalloc to call brk() system call to allocate data. Is this doable? Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, I need Firefox to allocate the data in Heap by sys_brk(). Does anyone know how to do that?
I set the --enable-dss at configuration, but the heap is still empty.